# Wordpress, creating a different website on a subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I got a wordpress website on the main domain and in a subdirectory I want got another third-party web application I would like to run.

Eg. www.example.com <-- stores the main Wordpress website
www.example.com/members <-- runs a third party web application.

Is this possible or should I host the web application in a subdomain instead?

Comment: Yes this will work(unless your app is configured to run from the main directory), you can use a separate .htaccess file for the sub directory as well if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using IIS, nginx or Apache.